# Extension of map $f:X \to Y$ to cone $CX$ when $X$ is compact subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ compact and $f:X\to Y$. Let $w=(0,0..0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb R$ and $C(X)$ be the union of all line segments joining points of $X$ to $w$. To show that $f$ extends to $C$ and if $f$ is homotopic to constant map then $f$ induces zero homomorphism $f_*$ on singular homology groups.

I can understand that this $CX$ is same as the topological cone we construct . But there we have $f$ is nullhomotpic iff $f$ extends to $CX$. Here how to claim that it always extends to $CX$ here when $X$ is given to be compact subset ?. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you are right: indeed one can construct a null homotopy $X\times[0,1]\to CX\to Y$.

Comment: Yes but for compact subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ the question states that $f$ can always be extended to $CX$ which I am not getting how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $f$ extends to $\bar{f}:CX\to Y$, I don't think compactness is needed, but rather that $f\simeq c$ for some constant map $c$ (i.e. nullhomotopic)

Note that the cone $CX$ together with the obvious maps $\pi:X\times I\to CX$ and $\iota:\operatorname{pt}\to CX$ can be regarded as the pushout of the diagram \begin{align*}
*\xleftarrow{\operatorname{pt}} X\xrightarrow{i=(\operatorname{id},0)} X\times I
\end{align*}so it satisfies the following universal property: For any topological space $Y$ together with morphisms $f:\operatorname{pt}\to Y,g: X\times I\to Y $ such that $g\circ i=f\circ \operatorname{pt} $, there is a unique morphism $h: CX\to Y$ such that $f=h\circ \iota$ and $g=h\circ \pi$.

Now, since $f$ is nullhomotopic, there is some homotopy $H:X\times I \to Y$ such that $H_0=c$, where $c$ is some constant map and $H_1=f$. But by the above universal property, there exists a (unique!) map $\bar{f}:CX\to Y$ such that $H=\pi\circ \bar{f}$. Since $H_1=f$, precomposing with $X\times \{1\}\hookrightarrow X\times I$ yields $\bar{f}|_X=f$.